# Back to School; Triple Lindy

Tags: trivia, swimming

In my younger years, I've seen this wonderful movie called [Back to School](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090685/). There [Rodney Dangerfield](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001098/?ref_=tt_cl_t1) alias [Thornton Melon](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0019596/?ref_=tt_cl_t1) performs the [Triple Lindy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rDMMYT3vkTk) ([1'09''](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=rDMMYT3vkTk#t=69)).

Has anybody ever seen a "Triple Lindy" being performed in real life or has a reference to an occurrence?

Comment: Haha, I highly doubt that anyone's ever actually done that. Very dangerous

Comment: Before anyone down votes this question, I have to say, I'd love to see proof that this was actually done sometime other than in the movie!

Comment: It is very difficult to prove that something has never been done.  But, no, this has never been done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching the internet for a possible answers, made me realize that this question has been asked many times before.

### The answer to the question is: no.

Below some of the things I found along the way.

1. In [this video (0'30")](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EtvsqHxNZ1w) on YouTube, an alleged attempt is made to
   perform a Triple Lindy, but I think it's just a faulty dive.
2. In [this interview](http://oldschool.tblog.com/post/1970109747), the director Alan Metter explains the origin
   of the Triple Lindy:

   > Q: I have to ask about the "Triple Lindy" dive. Who came up with the actual silly dive itself? How long did it take to film and were
   >   there any challenges?

   and the response of Alan:

   > A: The Triple Lindy was the vision of writer Michael Elias, Triple
   >   Lindy who I met on a television special for Steve Martin. He was
   >   talking with Rodney about the diving horse act on the boardwalk in
   >   Atlantic City in the 40s. Suddenly he said, "Hey, why don't you do an
   >   impossible dive...The Triple Lindy..." I knew immediately I had struck
   >   gold. What an idea! Rodney's sport had been swimming before this,
   >   which gave me pause. I knew diving was an event even out-of-shape
   >   Rodney could finish! Because of the tight schedule, I made the shots
   >   with Rodney and our editor, David Rollins, shot the double in one day
   >   with a second unit (thus the inconsistency in the light, if you look
   >   at it again). When I showed it to Rodney, we shook our heads in
   >   agreement that this might be the dumbest joke ever put on film. He
   >   loved it!

   The last remark makes it even more obvious that this dive has never been
   performed before !!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, the Triple Lindy has never been (successfully) performed in real life. I have heard of a few people attempting it, but none have been successful, because the only people skilled enough to perform it are also smart enough to realise that it's a stupid idea.

The YouTube video Jacob linked in his answer is certainly not a Triple Lindy attempt. Notice that the diver was still curled into a ball when he hit the adjacent springboard. Also note the "triple" in "Triple Lindy".

Answer (score -1):

I would have thought it impossible, but in about 1968, at a local pool, there was a college diver I only recall as Archie. Off a 3 meter board, he would do a reverse flip, land back on the board, continue through a 1 1/2, land on one of the side 1 meter boards, go into another forward 1 1/2, and then enter the water. 
At the Jones Beach west bathhouse, there were 5 boards. I’ve seen divers go off 2 different boards and cross in the air and some divers dive using multiple boards to complete a single dive comprised of multiple launches and landings.  Never saw one called a Triple Lindy, but have to believe someone can do it.